# Does a second chance ticket have any value?

Tags: gambling

If someone buys a ticket in a lottery and that ticket wins another ticket (in the same lottery), does the recipient have two chances at winning the jackpot or one?

Comment: I had the view that the first ticket is just subterfuge.

Comment: I think your question is a bit confused. Whether or not something is a "chance" is independent of what you *actually* win. That is, if there's a 1/100 chance of winning a lottery—and you buy one ticket and win another, then you've *had* two chances to win the money. Similarly, if you buy two tickets and win two stuffed consolation lions, you've also had two chances at the money.

Comment: i would say yes, but not simultaneously

Comment: If there were 50 tickets and they had a 1% chance of winning, I would expect the chances of the prize would be drawn to be 50%. If I also printed say 100000 second chance tickets, would the odds of the prize being drawn increase?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on if the new ticket is for the same drawing, and how the drawing is determined. If it is a match the winning numbers game then you have another chance to win, but your odds stay exactly the same.        There is also the event called "second chance drawing", if thats what you mean then The second chance is usually a raffle for a much smaller prize, but fewer people tend to send the ticket back for the second chance drawing. So the chance of winning the second chance drawing is much higher than winning the original jackpot. Usually the ticket must be mailed in to the lottery office to be entered into the raffle.

Comment: I edited my question to be clear. The ticket wins another ticket for the same prize. Thanks for your answer as it does clarify. I think consumer inertia can be disregarded for simplicity.

Comment: That would give you another chance at winning, but each ticket would still have the same odds in a standard lottery game. In a raffle where a winning ticket is always called the odds would depend on number of tickets sold, so having a larger percent of those tickets increases your odds of winning